# Reduce list of enum values to single int

Tags: c#

I have an enum which designates categories (columns) for some data.  I would like to be able to store a sorting order, so a list of these enums as a single int value.  So that no matter what the size of the list (within reason) there is a unique int that can reconstruct the list.

```
    public enum SortingCategories
    {
        ORDER_DATE = 1,
        CUSTOMER_STATE = 2,
        CUSTOMER_NAME = 3,
        CUSTOMER_HAIRCOLOR = 4,
        ...
    }

    public IEnumerable<SortingCategories> GetSortingOrder(int code)
    {
        ...
    }

    public int GetSortingCode(IEnumerable<SortingCategories> order)
    {
        ...
    }

    public const List<SortingCategories> PossibleSortingOrder = new List<SortingCategories>()
    {
        SortingCategories.CUSTOMER_NAME,
        SortingCategories.CUSTOMER_STATE,
        SortingCategories.ORDER_DATE,
        SortingCategories.CUSTOMER_HAIRCOLOR
    };

    public const List<SortingCategories> AnotherPossibleSortingOrder = new List<SortingCategories>()
    {
        SortingCategories.CUSTOMER_STATE,
        SortingCategories.CUSTOMER_HAIRCOLOR
    };
```

Comment: Can you provide more context as to **why** you're trying to do this?  That will help us guide you best.

Comment: Do you need to be able to reconstruct the order of the items in the list as well?

Comment: @reuben I would like to save a user's sorting order in a database

Comment: @jimmyjambles Are you truly limited to just representing this with a single `int`?  Or are you really looking for any way to store this sorting order efficiently in your database?

Comment: @reuben I guess the most efficient

Comment: @jimmyjambles ...so what's your database?  You might find it more helpful to rephrase your question into the broader goal you're trying to accomplish -- depending on the other specifics of your system, there might be a different approach to the problem that you hadn't considered (and which doesn't involve merging these integers).

Comment: @reuben I'm using SQL Server, to clarify, my question is mostly theoretical, I am aware that there are many ways that I can represent this data, I would like to discuss the most efficient way to represent it as a single int

Comment: @jimmyjambles Fair enough :)  Just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

How about just concatenating the values if they are < 10

Eg.

```
1324
2341
4231
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm wondering if there is a faster way to serialize and deserialize it to/from a single int this way, or a way that would support more than 10 different enum values

Comment: There's no reason it has to be base 10.  It could be base 11 or 12 or 13 ..., you're just trading off "number of unique items" for "number of positions in the list".  Position n is just (num / base pow n) % base.  n 0:whatever.  Integer division, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, the solution is to use binary flags for this purpose. This lets you save the options, but not the order. There is no way to save the selections AND there order in a single number unless you create flags for every legal combination. You could however, construct your own custom string format for such a list. i.e) {3}{6}{1} and cast those values as `SortingCategories` before doing the sort.

Here is how the flags option might look.

```
public enum SortingCategories
{
    ORDER_DATE = 0x1,
    CUSTOMER_STATE = 0x2,
    CUSTOMER_NAME = 0x4,
    CUSTOMER_HAIRCOLOR = 0x8,
    ...
}
```

Then use binary operators. i.e)

```
uint categories = SortingCategories.ORDER_DATE | SortingCategories.CUSTOMER_NAME;

if((categories & SortingCategories.ORDER_DATE) == SortingCategories.ORDER_DATE)
    do something...
```

Comment: I think you might have meant to start from `0x1`.

Comment: You are correct, I'll update it. I do use 0x0 but it always means NONE.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've set the enum up where each value is a unique power of 2, like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum SortingCategories
{
    ORDER_DATE = 1,
    CUSTOMER_STATE = 2,
    CUSTOMER_NAME = 4,
    CUSTOMER_HAIRCOLOR = 8,
}
```

You can use the [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method:

```
var myEnumList = new List<SortingCategories>()
{
    SortingCategories.CUSTOMER_NAME,
    SortingCategories.CUSTOMER_STATE,
    SortingCategories.ORDER_DATE,
    SortingCategories.CUSTOMER_HAIRCOLOR
};

var myEnumValue = myEnumList.Aggregate((x, y) => x | y);
```

---

**Update** this is a generalization from [*Rob van der Veer*'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20588967/1715579) answer which will work for `enum` types with up to 9 members—or more generally for `enum` types with *n* members it can encode lists up to *log*<sub>n</sub>(2<sup>31</sup>-1) items. It will ensure you can decode the integer to get the original list, including the order in which the items appeared in the list:

```
// Get the number of members in the enum type
// Note, you could hard code this as a private const as well
int numberOfMembers = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SortingCategories)).Length;


// Get integer value from enum list
int EnumListToInt(IEnumerable<SortingCategories> list, int numberOfMembers)
{
    return list.Aggregate(
        new { i = 0, p = 1 },
        (a, e) => new { i = (a.i + (int)e * a.p), p = a.p * numberOfMembers },
        a => a.i);
}

// Get integer value representing list
List<SortingCategories> EnumListToInt(int intVal, int numberOfMembers)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, numberOfMembers).Select(
        p => {
            var result = intValue % numberOfMembers;
            intValue /= numberOfMembers;
            return (SortingCategories)result;
        }).ToList();
}
```

Note that unlike the previous method, this method assumes the enum values range from 0 to *N*, as though you didn't specify any explicit values for the enum members. This could be modified to support any values by using something along the lines of:

```
int numberOfMembers = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SortingCategories)).Cast<int>().Max() + 1;
```

Comment: That will only mask the columns, not their order

Comment: @RobvanderVeer That's a good point, but it's not entirely clear that that's necessary.

Comment: True, i assumed that. It's kind of relevant if you are sorting columns. Must be a professional disorder to assume stuff. I apologize for thinking ahead.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer It seems your intuitions were correct. Inspired by your answer (+1 BTW) I've provided a solution that should work for enums with arbitrary numbers of members (within certain limits).